# PdfDocument in PdfView is crash with unrecognised selector instance in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdfview

I am using Xcode 9.4 with Objective C.
I want display pdf file using PDFView as per the below code

```
PDFView * pdfView = [[PDFView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
PDFDocument *pdfDocument = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:data];
[pdfView setDocument:pdfDocument];
```

But it fails with SetDocument unrecognised selector instance along with below error.

Error:

-[PDFView setDocument:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101367c40

error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

I am not able to identify the exact problem, please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running this on an iOS version lower than 11.0, by any chance?

Comment: No, iOS version is 11.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally,

I got the solution,
Just add UIView in storyboard and set the class as a PDFView in Inspector.
And create the IBOutlet object of PDFView and assign it to UIView in storyboard and set the pdfdocument to the PdfView along with properties if required.

Code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Swift" ofType:@"pdf"]];
    PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc]initWithURL:url];
    _pdfView.document = document;
    _pdfView.frame = self.view.frame;
    _pdfView.displayDirection = kPDFDisplayDirectionHorizontal;
```

Thank you all for your valuable efforts for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's PDFView documentation, there's a `document` property that holds the PDF document. Instead of calling `setDocument`, set the `document` property to your `pdfDocument` variable.

Comment: Actually I did more debugging and found that issue with PDFView.
all properties of PDFView giving same error as above.
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector. The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: Make sure none of the pointer variables in your code snippet are nil. That's the only other potential problem I see in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and for me the reason was that another developer had added the pod "UIImage-PDF" to our project, which also provides a class named PDFView but different interface.

Putting this answer here in case someone else had the same root cause for this issue than me.